# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

let $C= \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

There $\exists N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n>N$, it is true that: $$a_n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

We should prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists such a  $N\in\mathbb N$, for every $n>N$ $$\left|\frac1{a_n}\right|<\epsilon$$

So we take the N that satisfies the first conclusion, and that will mean for every $n>N$$$\left|\frac1{a_n}\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: $a_N \gt C$ whenever $n > N$ is probably a typo EDIT: or not, seems quite wayward from the definition of a limit. Go back to the definition of a limit.

Comment: Careful with the first inequality on your last "therefore" line.  Just because $n>N$ doesn't mean that $a_{n}>a_{N}$, i.e. that $\frac{1}{a_{n}}<\frac{a}{a_{N}}$.  It is true that if $n>N$ then $a_{n}>C$ and hence $\frac{1}{a_{n}}<\frac{1}{C}$.

Comment: I advise you try and make the proof by considering specifically what you need to show: i.e. for an $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\lvert\frac{1}{a_n}\rvert \lt \epsilon$ eventually.

Comment: "For every $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$", probably not the range you want, careful.

Comment: I think I have it, does it look okay now? @Veltas

Comment: Great! That's the idea, but you need to be slightly more careful, and your phrasing could be a bit better. Don't write things like "So we take the N that satisfies the first conclusion", try reordering what you've written. It's probably bad style to write "let $C = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$". Also $\left| a_n\right| \gt \frac{1}{\epsilon} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{1}{a_n}\right| \lt \epsilon$ for only a certain range of $\epsilon$, you need to identify this range and consider the other case.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer somthing like this (close to what you have):

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\infty$ means for any $C$ there is an $N$ such that $a_n \gt C$ for $n \gt N$

So given any $\epsilon \gt 0$, let $C = \frac1\epsilon$

and there is an $N$ such that $a_n \gt \frac1\epsilon \gt 0$  for $n \gt N$

i.e. $0 \lt \frac1{a_n} \lt \epsilon$  for $n \gt N$

and that implies $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n}=0$